# Access to Hbase over Thrift with Knox

Tags: hbase, thrift-protocol, knox-gateway, apache-knox

Hbase has a couple of wrapper services that help access it. They are Thrift and Rest services.

We are using Apache Knox to access these services. We can use Knox WEBHBASE service to access Hbase via Rest.

The question is: how can I use Knox to access Hbase via the Thrift service? Is this possible in general?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no :( the reason is that Knox does not support thrift it only supports http. Is there a specific reason you'd want to use thrift?

Comment: By the way, I found that we can start thrift in HTTP mode with an hbase configuration parameter "hbase.regionserver.thrift.http=true" (without kerberos and SSL), and this even works - I've checked this conf with some python code. but anyway don't sure is this possible use knox to proxy traffic to this

Comment: If it is http/s knox should be able to proxy it.